# Background blur for 18.04 unlock screen

Tags: 18.04, themes

I have added a background image to unlock screen of 18.04 using the below code in `ubuntu.css` in `usr/share/gnome-shell/theme`

```
#lockDialogGroup { background: #2e3436 url("unlock-background.jpeg"); background-repeat: none; background-size: cover; }
```

While it works great, is it possible to add a blur effect to whatever image we are using as unlock screen background ? Thanks.

Eg. Something close to the blur below

[image]

Possible solution from w3schools

```
/* Add the blur effect */
  filter: blur(8px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
```

I am not quite confident how to add this piece of CSS.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to blur your image using GIMP or an online tool and then use the blurred image as a background.

If you don't know how to use GIMP, i would recommend using this:
https://onlinejpgtools.com/blur-jpg

Just upload your image, enter the blur radius you want and download the resulting image.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I do now. But it would be good to just replace the image and leave blurring to the css code.

Comment: Check out these css filters then:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp

Comment: Please check the updated question. I am not good with CSS, So I would need some help here.

Comment: I think that just adding

`background {
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
  filter: blur(8px);
}`

inside `#lockDialogGroup` will work.

Comment: @user227495 did it work?

Comment: no, it didn't. I am not sure why.